# using photoSphere in my app

Tags: android, photosphere

I'm using this code to use photoSphere in my android app:

```
    @Override
public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
   uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.mu1);
   mClient.loadPanoramaInfo(this, uri);
}
```

and it works as intended. But when I tried to load a the same file from another path it failed and I don't know why..Do anyone have any idea why is this happening?

this it the code I use..:

```
       @Override
public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
   Uri uri = Uri.parse(MyApplication.getPhotoStorage()+"/mu1.jpg");
   mClient.loadPanoramaInfo(this, uri);
}
```

At first I thought the uri is wrong but then I used it to create a file and checked its size, and was as intended. I'd really appreciate any help

Comment: Hello @libathos I wanted to know that how did u get succeeded in using Photosphere in your app. Please help me with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I figured it out. Don't know why but apparently this wasn't the correct Uri of the file.so in order to get the  uri I used this function on the file

```
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
```

and it worked like a charm.Hopefully I'll help anyone that stumbles upon this post